# Only include sub-directory files in pre-commit hook

Tags: regex, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

Trying to add [nbqa](https://github.com/nbQA-dev/nbQA) hooks to a project, e.g.

```
      - id: nbqa-black
        name: nbqa-black
        entry: nbqa black
        language: system
```

however, I only want to run this hook on a directory for files such as:

`./notebooks/certain_notebook_folder/a_notebook.ipynb`
`./notebooks/certain_notebook_folder/one_more_level/another_notebook.ipynb`

I can get this to work for *all* ipynb files under notebooks like:

```
      - id: nbqa-black
        name: nbqa-black
        entry: nbqa black
        files: ^notebooks\/.*\.ipynb$
        language: system
```

(ignore neatness of using wildcards in regex)

I would therefore think that something like either of:

```
      - id: nbqa-black
        name: nbqa-black
        entry: nbqa black
        files: ^notebooks\/certain_notebook_folder\/.*\.ipynb$
        language: system
```

or

```
      - id: nbqa-black
        name: nbqa-black
        entry: nbqa black
        files: ^notebooks.*certain_notebook_folder.*\.ipynb$
        language: system
```

would work, but neither picks up any files. What have I overlooked?

Comment: show the command you're running and the output? it works fine for me

Comment: (you don't need to escape forward slashes -- it isn't a problem just unnecessary)